# Grant minimum required permission for adding computer to a domain - without using delegation

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, domain

Following principle of *Least-Privilege Administrative Model* I need to create custom group that would give its members permission to add computers to a domain but nothing else that could pose a security risk.

So I created my custom group in AD (let's call it "Domain Manager") and assigned test domain user to this group.
Then I went over to Group Policy Manager and created GPO. Inside my GPO I went to **Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment.** and added my custom group to **Add workstations to Domain** policy.

Exactly following Method 1 from this article:
https://www.prajwaldesai.com/allow-domain-user-to-add-computer-to-domain/

Next I linked GPO to an OU with a single computer just for testing (and ran `gpupdate /force` for good measure). I removed this computer from the domain and tried adding it again with credential of my test user (added to custom group) - it didn't work (got Access Denied error). Next I tried doing the same but assigning GPO to the whole domain - again the same error.

I've searched some more and found this note from Microsoft
[image]
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/access-denied-when-joining-computers

And it makes sense, as my testing computer was previously in the domain so I would need to reset password. But I'm not able to find this settings inside the GPO.

Is it possible to achieve this without using delegation? Am I missing something inside GPO?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have created a GPO policy for that, but you did not applied it correctly. The policy must be linked to OU with domain controllers, best to link it to the domain. You just assign that GPO policy to the specific security group and then it will work.

Comment: Oh, I will try that soon. But what about permission for resetting a password? Do I still need it and how to apply it via GPO?

Comment: You don't need permission for password resetting for adding AD computers. But you can create a separate security group or groups for user password management, for IT help desk or something. That is done in AD Users and Computers or AD Administrative Center by assigning permissions in OU-s for groups.

Comment: What about a note from Microsoft shown in the first post? They are saying that if computer previously existed in the domain then I would need password reset permission. Also I once assigned GPO to a whole domain (so to a domain controllers as well) and it didn't work.

Comment: @AnJ You must make sure that this GPO policy takes precedence over the GPO policy that prohibits users to add computers to AD, because you clearly have one.

Answer (score 0):

This capability usually requires more than that AD right. What you should do is create a group, and assign that group Create/Delete Computer objects permission for an OU, and the appropriate/desired permission at the OU for descendant Computer objects (delete/modify/custom permission). You can do the same for the Computers container, but it's more organized to not use that and create the Computers in the correct target OU to start with.